# Amazon MWS price feed, Override shipping price

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have a feed which sets the price of a book in my amazon inventory.

I am able to set the standard price of the book but I have no idea how to set the shipping price, I want to set the shipping price to 0, below is the current feed that I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>xxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <Price>
      <SKU>0115531310-New</SKU>
      <StandardPrice currency="GBP">50.01</StandardPrice>
    </Price>
  </Message>

</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tried yet, but should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>xxxx</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <Price>
      <SKU>0115531310-New</SKU>
      <StandardPrice currency="GBP">50.01</StandardPrice>
    </Price>
  </Message>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>2</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Override>
      <SKU>0115531310-New</SKU>
      <ShippingOverride>
        <ShipAmouunt currency="GBP">0.00</ShipAmouunt>
      </ShippingOverride>
    </Override>
  </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Maybe you can put the second Message into the first.

Comment: I don't think you can mix a shipping override feed with price feed.

Answer (score 0):

Its better send different feed for price and shipping cost

**for price feed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amznenvelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_SELLER_354577</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <Price>
            <SKU>ASUSVNA1</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="USD">10.99</StandardPrice>
        </Price>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <Price>
            <SKU>ASUSVNA1669</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="USD">204.99</StandardPrice>
            <Sale>
                <StartDate>2008-10-01T00:00:00Z</StartDate>
    Selling on Amazon – Guide to XML
    46
     <EndDate>2009-01-31T00:00:00Z</EndDate><SalePrice currency="USD">28.38</SalePrice></Sale>
        </Price>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

**For Shipping override**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>M_SELLER_354577</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Override</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Override>
Selling on Amazon – Guide to XML
53
 <SKU>487-6</SKU><ShippingOverride><ShipOption>Std Alaska Hawaii PO Box</ShipOption><Type>Additive</Type><ShipAmouunt currency="USD">20.00</ShipAmouunt></ShippingOverride><ShippingOverride><ShipOption>Exp Alaska Hawaii PO Box</ShipOption><IsShippingRestricted>false</IsShippingRestricted></ShippingOverride></Override>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Override>
            <SKU>487-5</SKU>
            <ShippingOverride>
                <ShipOption>Exp Alaska Hawaii PO Box</ShipOption>
                <Type>Additive</Type>
                <ShipAmouunt currency="USD">20.00</ShipAmouunt>
            </ShippingOverride>
            <ShippingOverride>
                <ShipOption>Exp Alaska Hawaii PO Box</ShipOption>
                <IsShippingRestricted>false</IsShippingRestricted>
            </ShippingOverride>
        </Override>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```